# CI/CD for Dell Boomi

Tags: deployment, continuous, boomi

Is there any possibility of applying DevOps concepts to build and Deploy Dell Boomi Processes.

Dell Boomi recommends usage of Atmosphere for change management activities, it also says its a UI based tool and we cannot export the code to a source control but have the following questions

1. Do we have any option to automate deployments across environments?
2. What kind of testing can be performed and at what stages?

Comment: I have got some details on test strategies [link](https://community.boomi.com/s/article/testingstrategies)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is a possibility to create a cross reference table with many columns including names of the process execution id, dates, action and so on and use it as a tool to deploy many processes from one place.

For the moment i was reading about it there was an issue because many developers who had an access to deployment could override values which made a lot of chaos.

Instead you can use 3rd party tool like jenkins.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf5MsQtEa5o

above example Boomi with Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AtomSphere API to automate deployments. In effect, you'll use a series of API calls to tell AtomSphere to automate the deployment of a given version of a package to an environment. This step is safe to repeat in many environments, and this way you can deploy to an arbitrary number of environments.

At a strategy level, testing Boomi is like any other integration tool. You should have unit tests, integration tests and systems tests. There are a range of techniques for each. Dell have some wiki pages that talk through unit testing approaches, specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Boomi isn't designed for CI/CD pipelines. There are nothing but dragons  on that journey. Better to work out your workflow for Folder use, and a type of Trunk-Based development approach within the tool than hack around it.

As for testing, most of what Boomi does is related to I/O and integrations, so Unit Tests are a waste of time for a system that has very little actual written code (or way to mock connectors properly). IMHO, focus on Integration and Functional tests. Unit Tests will always pass in a Boomi process and are therefore of no value. And in the rare case where they fail, an Integration test would also have failed, so you gained nothing from your efforts.

</2cents>